# How to find the value of $\vert x\vert ^y$ where $n,y\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I saw this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256762/variation-of-vert-f-vert1-5).  Now the question is above my *current* ablility.  I understand what is written but I don't believe I understand the meaning of what is written.

So step one I need to understand is:

**How to find the exponent of the absolute value of a number**

I know that the abs of a number is *distance*, depending upon which space one is in.

But, absolute values have two conditions and $(-3)^3 \neq (3^3)$  So that is my question.

Could someone explain with at least one example of how to take the exponent of the absolute value of a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the absolute value first, then raise to the power.  This is nice in that the base is then known to be positive, and raising to a real power is defined.  So $|-3|^4=3^4=81$ and $|-8|^{\frac 12}=8^{\frac 12}=2\sqrt 2$